# Collection View - Selected cell not updated when out of View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView within a View Controller. When the cell is clicked it updates the image associated with the cell. However, when a cell isSelected and then scrolled out of view and another cell is selected, it appears as the isSelected == true image until it is brought out and back into view once more. Images below hopefully describe the action better.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        // Configure the cell
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            
            if cell.isSelected {
                let image = imageArray1[indexPath.row]
                cell.cellImage.image = image
                return cell
            } else {
                let image = imageArray2[indexPath.row]
                cell.cellImage.image = image
                return cell
            }
      }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {            
        
            guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell else {
                        return
                    }
                    // deselect unused
                    cell.isSelected = false
                    cell.cellImage.image = imageArray2[indexPath.row]
            }
      }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell     
    cell?.isSelected = true
    cell.cellImage.image = imageArray1[indexPath.row]

}
```

**Step 1:** First cell is selected and changes to red image.
[image: First cell is selected and changes to red image.]

**Step 2:** Selected first cell is out of view and 5th cell is now selected, which should make cell 1 turn back to grey image.
[image: Selected first cell is out of view and 5th cell is now selected, which should make cell 1 turn back to grey image.]

**Step 3:** first cell should be unselected but when it is brought back into view it is still showing as selected. It will change back to grey image if it goes out and back into view once more.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to reload the collectionView? Just the first guess.

Comment: Unless you are saving the selected state for each cell in imageArray1, what you are expecting won't happen.